# GCM Push notification string post data send to GCM server from 3rd party server(.Net server)

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

```
String postdata= "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=2419200&delay_while_idle=1&data.message=‌​"
                + message + "&data.time=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString()
                + "&registration_id=" + deviceToken + "";
```

Confused with collapse_key and delay_while_idle flag. My notification is news. So now when the device is active, I am getting the notification in proper manner. But facing problem while it is idle(offline,locked or switched off). If two notifications has been send while the device was in idle state, it should receive both notifications whenever it comes to active. Should I append incremental value to collapse_key????? And in developer site it is given that delay_while_idle flag should be true. So i have set it to 1, but someone recommended me to set delay_while_idle=0. Please check the above screen and let me know if there is any correction.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to receive both notifications only when device becomes active again, leave delay_while_idle = true and increment/alter the collapse_key.

If you want the message(s) to appear even when the phone is locked/asleep, then set the delay_while_idle false.

Comment: Now for an example take three devices. First device is always active and online, Second device is locked/asleep(but it is connected to internet), Third device is offline. Now if two notifications has been send from the server, first device will receive both notifications; second should receive both notifications whenever it becomes active; third device should receive both notifications whenever it is again online and also active. This is my requirement,now please tell me what should be the value of delay_while_idle and collapse_key??? Note that I have added Wake_lock permission to manifest

Comment: Set the values as in my answer.

Comment: Thanx NickT. Then I am leaving delay_while_idle = true and incrementing the collapse_key. Because I need the notification(s) when the device is active. Using those values just want to confirm that if the device is offline or locked/asleep when the messages are been send, the moment the device becomes active it will receive the notifications or not....Please answer this point, I am confused at this part

Comment: According to the documentation it should get the message when it becomes active. I have not tested this myself, as I always have d.w.i false in my app.

Comment: Ok NickT. For your app have you ever tested or came across that if your device comes to active from idle state, and it receives the notification. Because I don't why in my case I am not receiving if my device is coming to active state from idle state.

Comment: I have just run a test and changed delay_while_idle to true in my script. If I send a message to my phone whilst it is idle, then it  gets received as soon as I press the home key to light up the screen, then unlock it. I normally have d.w.idle set to false so messages are received even when idle.

Comment: Then do you are getting what is the issue in my case???? Why I am not getting notification sometime(may be due to idle)???? Is it only because of collapse_key or any other issue. Note I have mentioned wake_lock permission in manifest. Do I have to create a another broadcast receiver in my activity and write wakelock.acquire() in onreceive of that receiver..I have not done because it is already done in GCMIntentService.Please suggest

Comment: I can only suggest that it might be due to your carrier or device, I have no more ideas, sorry.

Comment: Thank you for providing your time.I have found the problem. It is receiving in idle state. But if the device is offline when the push message has been send, then when the device is getting online, it is not receiving that pending notification. Now I have appended a incremental value to collapse_key and using delay_while_flag = true(1). Just asking do you have included wakelock.acquire and wakelock.release in generatenotification method(GCMIntentService class). Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: Glad you fixed it. I have not acquired any wakelocks in that class.

Comment: I have also checked using delay_while_idle =0, getting notification if the device is active or in locked/asleep. But still not getting notification if it is offline when message has been send. I should receive when it is active.